# Wanted to log component location once after Component movement completed in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to display the target location as 
Component moved to location - Xloc:634.0, yloc:394.0

```
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ComponentEventDemo extends JFrame {
  public ComponentEventDemo() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(400, 400);
    this.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ComponentEventDemo component = new ComponentEventDemo();
    component.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        logLocation(component);
      }
    });

  }

  public static void logLocation(ComponentEventDemo component) {
    System.out.println("Component moved to location - Xloc:" + component.getBounds().getMinX() + ", yloc:"
        + component.getBounds().getMinY());
  }
}
```

On moving my frame I want the frame location after completion of the movement

I am getting multiple logs for a single move event like

**Sample Output**

"Component moved to location - Xloc:0.0, yloc:0.0

Component moved to location - Xloc:5.0, yloc:2.0

Component moved to location - Xloc:15.0, yloc:11.0

Component moved to location - Xloc:29.0, yloc:24.0

Component moved to location - Xloc:50.0, yloc:41.0

Component moved to location - Xloc:76.0, yloc:64.0

Component moved to location - Xloc:113.0, yloc:95.0

Component moved to location - Xloc:150.0, yloc:124.0

Component moved to location - Xloc:191.0, yloc:154.0

Component moved to location - Xloc:238.0, yloc:185.0

Component moved to location - Xloc:288.0, yloc:214.0"

**I am looking for last log after mouse released.**

Thank you for the suggestion. I have made changes to my code as below
`

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ComponentEventDemo extends JFrame {
  Timer timer = new Timer(500, new MyTimer());
  static ComponentEventDemo component;

  public ComponentEventDemo() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(400, 400);
    this.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    component = new ComponentEventDemo();
    component.addListener(component);
  }

  public void addListener(final ComponentEventDemo component) {

    component.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        timer.start();
      }
    });
  }

  class MyTimer implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      logLocation();
      timer.stop();
    }
  }

  public void logLocation() {
    System.out.println("Component moved to location - Xloc:" + component.getBounds().getMinX() + ", yloc:"
        + component.getBounds().getMinY());
  }
}
```

`
It reduced the number of logs in output but not achieved the complete goal..
Looking for other options.. Thanks for any help in advance..

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for last log after mouse released.

There is no way to get that information since the dragging of the frame is controlled by the OS and you don't have access to the mouse events generated on the frame.

What you can try to do is use a Swing Timer. You schedule the Timer to fire after a certain time period, lets say 500ms.

In the componentMoved event you start/restart the Timer. So if the user continually drags the frame, the Timer will not fire. Then if the user doesn't drag the frame for 500ms the Timer event will be generated and you can get the current frame location.

So, yes, using this solution there will always be some delay in knowing the frames location.

Comment: adding swing timer reduced the number of lines printed. Thank you, but looking for other alternatives

Comment: `adding swing timer reduced the number of lines printed.` - why is this important? If we know the actual requirement, not your attempted solution, we might be able to help suggest an alternative.

Comment: we have a swing application where, users some times complain that the application is not visible on screen.  If we log the application location when changed then it will help us to trouble shoot the similar issues easily.

Comment: thought of adding my attempted solution but stopped because it is still adding multiple lines to log which is not accepted